# ImportError: No module named ***** in python

Tags: python, python-import

I am very new to python, about one month, and am trying to figure out how the importing works in python. I was told that I can import any 'module' that has Python code in it. So I am trying to import a module just to try it out, but I keep getting an 'ImportError: No module named redue'. This is an example of the python shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('C:\Users\Cube\Documents\Python')
>>> for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
     print file
pronounce.py
pronounce.pyc
readwrite.py
rectangle.py
reduc.py

>>> import reduc

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    import reduc
ImportError: No module named reduc
```

What am I doing wrong? I am I overlooking something, or was I just wrongly informed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These files are not on sys.path. It should have been though.

If you want to access them from the interpreter, you will need to add the location to sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
>>> sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Cube\\Documents\\Python')
>>> import reduc
```

You could also include the path in environment variable - PYTHONPATH

See the details on module search path here :

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path
- http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path

Also look at (PYTHONPATH) environment variable details here:

- http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

Comment: Isn't the current working directory usually in the search path?

Comment: @sth: It should have worked! It is difficult to check out why. So I just wanted to ensure that it is on sys.path and if there are other errors than we could follow up.