# Jython, unresolved import - java class

Tags: python, jython

I'm trying out jython, and got stuck pretty early with the example from chapter 10 http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html the math import does work from the java library. But I cannot get the custom class Beach to work.

I saw an identical post [Jython won't import user-defined class; ImportError: No module named ******](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824968/jython-wont-import-user-defined-class-importerror-no-module-named) 
However I did not understand the accepted answers approach.

So I'm hoping for a bit clarification.

Below is my project structure.

[image]

```
import Beach

b = Beach("Cocoa Beach","Cocoa Beach")
print (b.getName(Beach.getName()))
```

import Beach: Unresolved import: Beach

EDIT: Got it working with the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Users\Rasmus\Desktop')

import Beach

beach = Beach("Cocoa Beach","Cocoa Beach")
beach.getName()
print(beach.getName())
```

However pydev eclipse still marks import Beach as an unresolved import.

The Beach class

```
public class Beach {

    private String name;
    private String city;


    public Beach(String name, String city){
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see the class file in your directories. Did you run "javac src/Beach.java"? Only after doing that will you get a class file. It is a good practice to keep files of each language in a separate directory. Move your .java files to a Java directory and create a Java project for the same. Put your python files in a separate directory.

Comment: I made two seperate directories. Are there any way to make python create the java.class file by itself, so that I made easily edit my java classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the compiled class in Jython class path. You can only import compiled class files.

As metioned in the link that you had in your question:

> As we had learned in Chapter 8, one thing you’ll need to do is ensure that the Java class you wish to use resides within your CLASSPATH. In the example above, I created a JAR file that contained the Beach class and then put that JAR on the CLASSPATH.

The compilation is done by using [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) command which is part of JDK. Creating a [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jar.html) file is done with the command jar command part of JDK.

It is not a good practice to have files of different files in the same directory. You should create a Java project for your .java file and the Jython files in a separate directory.

Look at [using-a-jar-or-java-project-in-your-jython-app](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html#using-a-jar-or-java-project-in-your-jython-app).

Comment: Which I have no idea about how to proceed with.

Comment: I tried exporting my class Beach as a jar file, and pasted it into the src folder of the jyt project. But that did not do it. Isn't src the classpath?

Comment: Java source file need to be compiled using Javac and then you will get a .class file.

Comment: I did get it to work now. But it still complains and says it's unresolved import?

Comment: Did you add to classpath following directions at https://wiki.python.org/jython/LearningJython#classpath-and-python-path

Comment: I tired adding it with the append, but still shows there's an error. Are there any way for jython to do these steps automatically?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the class that you created and the jar file. Show the classpath changes.