# pulp installation testing didn't work

Tags: python, error-handling, installation, syntax-error, pulp

I have started following the instructions from http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html#installation , I installed PuLP using "Windows Installation from source"

When I type `from pulp import *` it gave the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import pulp
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.6-py3.4.egg\pulp\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .pulp import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.6-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 114, in <module>
    from odict import OrderedDict
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\odict.py", line 614
    raise TypeError, ('pop expected at most 2 arguments, got %s' %
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please help me to overcome the issue?

Comment: As it says, it's a Syntaxerror.

Comment: Hi Rickard, I apologize for my rookie question. I just installed pulp. Where should I work for the SyntaxError?

Comment: You should look in the file:
__init__.py in the python34 folder.

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.6-py3.4.egg\pulp\__init__.py

Comment: It looks like a problem in the source code when installed, so i would recommend using the other installing options.(easyinstall,...)

Comment: Alright. I started again from http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html#installation , I followed "Easy install and pypi installation". This time error message is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from pulp import*
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\pulp\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from amply import *
ImportError: No module named 'amply'

Comment: As it says, there is no module named amply. I do not know if it is an error from the python plu itself or if you are doing anything wrong. i personally do not use python plu and this is as fair as i can go to help you without installing it myself. try searching for **amply import * importError: No module named 'amply'** or **Python plu no module named 'amply'** also try to look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named or this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992952/importerror-no-module-named-in-python?rq=1