# ImportError: No module named Leap

Tags: python, leap-motion

I have started working on Leap Motion Controller and when trying to execute my code I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named Leap
```

I have added the path to the required libraries

```
import sys 
sys.path.append("usr/lib/Leap:/path/to/lib/x86:/path/to/lib")
import thread, time
from Leap import CircleGesture, KeyTapGesture, ScreenTapGesture, SwipeGesture
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am working on a Linux platform: Ubuntu 13.10, 32-bit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992952/importerror-no-module-named-in-python Check this question/answer. Also https://github.com/openleap/PyLeapMouse/issues/16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't append a colon separated path list like this, as Python's [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) stores the path entries an a list, and not a colon separated list. Each folder needs to be appended separately. Also, `usr/lib/Leap` looks to be missing the leading slash.

Something like this should work:

```
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/Leap")
sys.path.append("/path/to/lib/x86")
sys.path.append("/path/to/lib")
```

Or this:

```
sys.path += ["/usr/lib/Leap", "/path/to/lib/x86", "/path/to/lib"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.path` is not a string, it's a list of strings.  So append individual path strings to it, not one single pathsep-delimited string:

```
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/Leap")
sys.path.append("/path/to/lib/x86")
sys.path.append("/path/to/lib")
```

Alternatively you can `extend` the list by adding another list of strings—for example, the list you get by calling `split` on your string:

```
sys.path += "/usr/lib/Leap:/path/to/lib/x86:/path/to/lib".split( ":" )
```

But ideally you should check whether each string is already on the path before adding, otherwise the path will get indefinitely long and redundant with repeated calls. For example:

```
for p in "/usr/lib/Leap:/path/to/lib/x86:/path/to/lib".split( ":" ):
     if p not in sys.path: sys.path.append( p )
```